# Transferring Javascript Web App to Linux App

Tags: javascript, python, linux, ubuntu

Well, perhaps this is silly but I wonder is it possible, to transfer a web app built in Javascript with some html and css to linux platform?

I made a youtube player smth like youtube client, and I want to use on my Ubuntu 15.04 OS, as an app.

Here is a preview:
[image: youtubeviewer]

and I would love it if it would look smth like this:
[image: Google Mail Application on Ubuntu 15.04]

I know that this Google Mail is just loaded from a web, but I want to make it accessible from my Ubuntu. Just instead of this google I ant that my app gets in. I hope you understand...

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear. It seems you alreay have the web app accessible from linux. Are you asking if it's possible to run the web app w/o a browser?

Comment: I don't want to open it through the browser, that is Firefox. My App is running on apache2 server, I want to make it installable to Ubuntu...

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js - that may do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, JavaScript and HTML5 don't "natively" run on Linux -- so you'll have to find an application to wrap yours. Plenty of these things exist -- [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) is very popular, as is [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll try to take a stab at answering your question:

1. If you want to run it natively on linux without any other application being involved the answer to your question is not without rewriting it to some other language. Linux does not run javascript natively.
2. If you want something thinner then a web browser perhaps something exists to run your web app for you, but it's essentially going to be a light web browser. If you want to run javascript there will always be some other application between you and the kernel unless the kernel specifically supports javascript which Linux does not (and AFAIK no kernel does).

So in short, based on what I think you're asking for, no.

Comment: Using the light web browser was my idea, but how to do that I don't know...

Comment: Well, then you'll have to be more specific about what exactly it is about a web browser that you don't like.